# jqGrid. How to change the list of dropdownlist based on a present value in a row in edit mode?

Tags: php, mysql, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid to display data from a MySQL database. 
To add or edit a line I have in a dll that I display with in jqgrid :

```
{name:'proj_id', index:'proj_id', width:30,
            editable:true,
            edittype:"select", 
            editoptions:{   
                    dataUrl:'ddl/ddl_projet.php',
                    }// end edit option
        },
```

and my query ddl_projet.php :

```
include("../dbconfig.php");

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM t_projet 
        WHERE proj_id IN (4,5,9,21,22,23,24)
        ORDER BY proj_projet ASC";

echo '<select>';

$result = $dbh->prepare($SQL);
$result->execute();

while($row = $result->fetch()) {

     echo '<option value="'.$row['proj_id'].'">'.$row['proj_projet'].'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```

I had to limit the number of my ddl in the list because I no longer uses them all. 
So I did this in my query : WHERE proj_id IN (4,5,9,21,22,23,24)

But when I want to edit a row with a value that was present earlier in the ddl, the form in this edition don't show me of course this value. 
How can I change the content of the ddl based on values ​​of the edit?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're manually managing active/inactive projects. It would be better to a new field in the table to manage the status of the projects (or have some other way to differentiate the project status).  You can group projects based on their status and then display accordingly.

This sample might help
http://www.trirand.net/demo/php/jqpivotgrid/